# Relationship between node and taxonomy term using migrate_d2d_ui

Tags: 7, migrations, upgrading

I used [Migrate 7.x-2.6-rc1+30-dev](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) and [Migrate_d2d_ui 7.x-2.1-beta1](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module to upgrade my "Drupal 6" website to D7, everything went fine but the node-to-taxonomy relation seems to have got lost. How to relink the relation in the imported data ?

Below is the snapshot from setting form:

This didn't work for me: https://drupal.org/node/2063203

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting values from the d6 db, but it is not mapping properly you can likely use `public function prepare($node, $row) {...}` on your migrate object to map the taxonomy terms from the d6 site to the d7 version. Off the top of my head I don't know how that looks, but that is where I would start. prepare !